# What would be the python equivalent of this Perl if condition?

Tags: python, mysql, perl

I am new to Perl and I'm having trouble understanding this code. What does the if condition check here?

```
my $ret = 0;
my @r = ();
if(@r = $sth->fetchrow_array()){
        $ret = $r[0];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition is a list assignment. `if` enforces boolean, i.e. scalar context; arrays in scalar context return their size. Therefore, the condition is true if the array is populated, false if it's empty.

The method `fetchrow_array` most probably comes from [DBI](http://p3rl.org/DBI). It returns a row from a database result. If there are no more rows or if there's an error, it doesn't return anything: that would make the condition false.